# IronRouter data property runs before waitOn?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Say that I have this route:

```
  Router.route('/order', {
    template: 'order',
    name: 'order',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('orders');
    },
    data: function(){
      return Orders.findOne()._id;
    }
  });
```

In server folder:

```
Meteor.publish('orders', function(){
  return Orders.find();
});
```

On page load, I get `cannot read property '_id' of undefined`, pointing to `Orders.findOne()._id`

But I open Chrome Console and do `Orders.findOne()._id` and it pops up with an id immediately.

For some reason it seems like `data` is being run before the subscription in `waitOn` is ready? I'm using the latest Iron Router.

Comment: Could you share your publish()? Also, will there only be one order or is this handled in the publish()?

Comment: You can try `var data = Orders.findOne(); return data && data._id` until you find the actual answer, I think.

Comment: @smoksnes, I've added my publish. It's just a standard "publish everything." There are currently numerous orders in the Orders collection.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I had to do to remove the error and get my route to function normally:

```
  Router.route('/order', {
    name: 'order',
    template: 'order',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('orders');
    },
    data: function(){
      if( this.ready() ){
        return Orders.findOne()._id
      };
    },
  });
```

I had to put `this.ready()` inside of the `data` function, which is incredibly strange because I don't think I've ever needed to do this before in the past, and I don't see anyone mentioning having to do this in Iron Router?

Regardless, people say that Iron Router's `data` function can be buggy and it constantly re-runs router code because Iron Router thinks there should be reactivity in the router. I don't know what's going on with this.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `data` is run when the template renders, and `action` controls that. Try adding this:

```
  Router.route('/order', {
    template: 'order',
    name: 'order',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('orders');
    },
    data: function() {
      return Orders.findOne()._id;
    },
    action: function() {
      if(this.ready()) {
        this.render();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Still not working. There is something very, very strange going on. I disabled ALL of my routes except for this one and wrote it exactly like you did above. I still get `cannot read property '_id' of undefined` but after the page loads I can do `Orders.findOne()._id` in the console and it returns an ID.

Comment: Looking at my debuggers, debugger stops first on the `waitOn` function, then on the `data` function, then on the `waitOn` function *again*,  then on the `action` function that checks for `this.ready()` - it's `true`, so it renders the page, then on the `data` function *again*... and that's it. I've removed and re-added iron-router. All packages updated.